# Whenever-capistrano deploy issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, whenever, whenever-capistrano

Using whenever gem to manage cron jobs for my Rails 3.2.13 app. 
Deploying with Capistrano.

Here is what I get in the outpout:

```
/home/marcele/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@models/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:18:in `instance': Please require this file from within a Capistrano recipe (LoadError)
from /home/marcele/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@models/gems/whenever-0.8.3/lib/whenever/capistrano/recipes.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/marcele/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@models/gems/whenever-0.8.3/lib/whenever/capistrano.rb:1:in `require'
from /home/marcele/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@models/gems/whenever-0.8.3/lib/whenever/capistrano.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from ./config/deploy.rb:62:in `require'
```

The deploy.rb receipe is over here (withought the heads): https://gist.github.com/Almaron/5989804.
It works fine if I remove lines 61 and 62 mentioning whenever.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - not enough sleep.
Moved the require statement out of the namespace and everything is fine.